# Is there a classical quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, decoherence

Some people always say that quantum mechanics can't be described by classical mechanics and that quantum mechanics works only in isolated and cold systems, but on the other hand, there are also lasers and computers which can be described by quantum mechanics. So are lasers and computers described by classical mechanics or quantum mechanics? Where is the line? If lasers and computers can only be described by quantum mechanics, how do they work? Because neither of it are isolated systems.

Comment: 'Some people always say that' This is an insufficient reference. Some people will say just about anything.

Comment: Bohr's Model can be classified under classical quantum mechanics

Answer (score 6):

Quantum mechanics works (as far as we can tell) in all systems (although we still haven't settled on a way to get relativistic gravity to work nicely with quantum mechanics). Quantum mechanics definitely applies to non-isolated systems and to hot systems. There are just more complications when you want to describe a non-isolated system (you have to take into account interactions with the environment), and there are more complications when you want to describe hot systems (you have to take statistical mechanics into account). In general, classical mechanics is a good approximation for large-scale phenomena, and quantum mechanics is used for small-scale phenomena. However, quantum mechanics is applicable to large-scale phenomena as well. The effects are just usually not as noticeable (although there are exceptions to this), and people tend to prefer classical mechanics if they can get away with it because it's easier.